# Флаг "Сообщения плохого качества" используется неверно

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, модерация, правила

Замечаю, что флаг "Сообщения плохого качества" зачастую используется неверно. Часто его ставят тем вопросам, которые должны быть просто приостановлены (то, что называется *[требует правки]*), а не удалены.

Смотрим описание флага: *"У данного вопроса серьезные проблемы с форматированием или содержанием. Поскольку маловероятно, что его удастся улучшить с помощью правок, этот вопрос нужно **удалить**."*

И описание действия в очереди проверок: *"Закрыть , если данный вопрос невозможно улучшить, и его следует немедленно **удалить**."*

На оригинальном SO такая проблема тоже была и есть, народ просто не понимает, что значит этот флаг. А значит он вкратце следующее: **"Этот вопрос/ответ совершенно, невозможно ужасен. Я не могу смотреть на него ни единой секунды, так как мои глаза начинают кровоточить. Немедленно удалите его с сайта"**.

Вот [ссылка на обсуждение на оригинальном SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280342/low-quality-wrong-but-not-low-quality)

Можем ли мы сделать что-то, чтобы суть флага была более очевидна?

---

Примеры:

[раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19350) ответ принят и имеет два плюса. Да, очень короткий. Но удалять зачем?

[два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18921) ну зачем это сразу удалять?

[три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19357) опять таки, это не к удалению.

[четыре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19498) нормальный вопрос, на мой взгляд, ни одного минуса. Удалить?

[пять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19470)- тут надо просто было связаться с автором и попросить добавить код.

---

Контрпример: зато [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437741/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) всего лишь закрыли, хотя надо было сразу удалять.

Comment: **5** — это я отметил. Если в ответе только ссылка — он должен быть комментарием. «Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.»

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ага, интересно. Получается, что флаг к ответу "надо сделать комментарием" и флаг "все очень, очень плохо" распознаются системой одинаково. Мне такая система не нравится.

Comment: В общем-то, с такими случаями, как **5**, я бы рекомендовал сначала дергать автора, особенно если он часто появляется на сайте. Т.к во времена стародавние, на Хэшкоде, я иногда тоже такими ответами грешил.

Comment: согласен, вариант «заменить ссылку на решение» это гораздо лучше, чем когда там «Ага, я гуглил и нагуглил сюда». Может быть, стоит как-то разделить эти варианты.

Comment: *тут надо просто было связаться с автором и попросить добавить код* Сдается мне, добавить код в ответ трехлетней давности не всегда реально.

Comment: @Olter Удалять может только модератор. В случае необходимости удаления, наилучший способ использовать сигнал тревоги.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я так и сделал, просто к тому моменту, когда я увидел этот вопрос, он уже был закрыт, а закрытым вопросам нельзя ставить флаг "плохого качества", только "требует вмешательства модератора"

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте ответ верным за недостатком других вариантов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спешу предложить изменить заголовок причины тревоги с "`очень низкого качества`" на "`вопрос необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством`". Сама формулировка, на мой взгляд, однозначная.

Как ни странно, для ответов, заголовок и формулировка тревоги достаточно однозначные.